# Redux Action js file

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

i have a code that looks something like this in the redux action

```
fetchAction (route) => {
   return {
     action1: {}
   }[route] 
}
```

`if route = "action1"` it does return me back the whole object of `action1`
how does that `[route]` help to get back the object ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understand it like this

```
fetchAction (route) => {
   return {
     action1: {}
   }[route] 
}

fetchAction (route) => {
   var obj = {
     action: {}
   }
   return obj[route] 
}

fetchAction (route) => {
   var obj = {
     action: {}
   }
   var returnObj = obj[route]
   return returnObj;
}
```

Comment: OH !!!! NOW I SEE IT !!! THANK YOU ! is this a good way of coding ? it really got me confused ...

Comment: It is totally upto you. There is no harm doing it this way if all the developers in your team are able to understand this. But personally, it will waste time for new developers to understand this pattern.

Comment: i confused the outer curly braces with those of the if statement i didn't realise the whole thing was an object lol. Thank you very much